# Why is the Select Device grayed ( In Android Studio Code ), even If there is not error in my Code

Tags: select, device

So I am New to Android Studio Code and i have just opened my Android Studio code, after a 2 Weeks later.
and just saw that my Project is not running on my device, AndroidStudioCode is not even Building Gradle or doing the App Installation process.
[As you can see in this image that the Select Device Area is grayed,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nLh6.png)

**each time i click on the Run Button, i get this **
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSz7Y.png)

I want my app to run on my Android Device

Comment: [How to connect your Android device (link to: developer.android.com)](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-connect-device#0)